# Overlap DIV with one another

Tags: html, css, overlap

I have following html code:

```
<div id="waterSummaryContainer_#{chartIndex.index}" style="min-width: 440px; height: 250px; margin: 0 auto; float:left;"></div>
```

The output is coming as following:
[image]

I want to make some space between the two charts. What do I need to change in css so that it will not overlap with each other.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Can you give us more about the HTML code?

Comment: Are you using `position: absolute`?

Comment: Yeah, give us a jsFiddle or something to play with to see your problem.

Comment: margin-right:50px or so? We could use more html...

Comment: I am using style="min-width: 440px; height: 250px; margin: 0 auto; float:left;"

Comment: MOAR CODE -- if you have two divs with those CSS styles, they'd just sit next to each other (assuming their container had at least 880px). You've got other CSS affecting these divs.

Comment: It seems like both the charts are being rendered in a same div. Check you chart api to learn how to render it in two divs seperately. Are you using Highcharts? Show some fiddle if you want more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
display:inline-block;
```

This should fix your problem as long as the parent div is big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Change the margin in your style attribute.

```
style="min-width: 440px; height: 250px; **margin: 0 25px 0 0;** float:left;"
```

That should give you some space between the two divs